# Как инициализировать Ключ API для веб-приложения в firebase?

Tags: android, api, firebase, firebase-web-api

Я создал проект в `Firebase Console`, добавил пакет приложения.
Скачал `google-services.json` файл.
Мне необходимо получить `"Ключ API для веб-приложения"`, но его нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В значение `"Отсутствует ключ API для этого проекта."`.
В чем дело, какие шаги необходимо выполнить, чтобы получить значение `"Ключ API для веб-приложения"`?

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашел ответ... может кому-то понадобиться.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]